# problem with gradle dependencies - recyclerview and cardview

Tags: android

I am trying to implement cardview and recyclerview. But I am getting this error

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.1.1 Show in File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.1 Show in
>   File Show in Project Structure dialog

this is my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:21.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Try to use latest `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: Please use same version of com.android.support libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use the latest `implementation` dependency prefix instead of the obsolete `compile` configuration for all your dependencies. Second try to use the latest dependencies which as of now is `27.1.1` (stable). And about the Gradle build error, there must be a connection failure which usually caused by an interrupted internet connection or working with Gradle on offline mode and etc.

Try to check these options to troubleshoot:

1. Open Android Studio settings (Ctrl + Alt + S on Windows) and type HTTP Proxy on the search field then select the setting from left menu and use the **Check connection** button with some google repository address like https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml and wait for a **Connection successful** message, anything else means your proxy or internet connection is somehow the culprit and you need to seek there for a solution.
2. Make sure you're ***not*** using Gradle in **offline mode** which can be done in Settings> Build, Execution, Deployment> Gradle and the "Offline work" check must be off.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Though it could be version conflicts with appcompat lib.

**But**, Update your Target APIs to Android 8... see here.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

So, your gradle file should look like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode = code
        versionName = "ver name"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of incorrect version.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' //same as other support library vesion you used.
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
```